# How to make a simple EQ AudioUnit (bass, mid, treble) with iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, signal-processing, audiounit

does anyone know how to make a simple EQ audio unit (3 bands - low, mid, hi) with iOS ? I know how to add an iPod EQ Audio Unit to my AU Graph. But it only give you access to presets and I need proper control of the EQ.

I've looked around for some tutorials or explanations but no luck.

Thanks.

André

Answer (score 14):

The iPhone doesn't exactly support custom AudioUnits.  Or, more precisely, [it doesn't allow you to register an AudioUnit's identifier](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Coreaudio-api/2008/Nov/msg00274.html) so you could load it in an AUGraph.  You can, however, register a render callback, get raw PCM data, and process it accordingly.  This is how I've implemented effect processing in the iPhone.

Comment: This is indeed what I do. Would you have any example of a simple EQ code to point me to by any chance ? Thanks.

Comment: The best resource for sample DSP code is musicdsp.org.  Here you can find a sample 3-band EQ: http://musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=3#236  Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if you find it helps solve your problem. ;)

Comment: People looking for example code on how to implement an equalizer in iOS should really check this out: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP/blob/master/Examples/Equalizer.mm This will save you quite some time figuring out the posts at musicdsp.org, since I already implemented the best filter method possible.

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend you to use my [NVDSP library](http://bartolsthoorn.github.com/NVDSP/), it allows easy audio DSP'ing, including the filters required to make an equalizer in iOS: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP

Comment: I'm quite certain it will answer your question, let me know if you have any problems with the library. I also added the pieces of code required to make a 10 band equalizer: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP/blob/master/Examples/Equalizer.mm Also, I see you've been trying to figure out CoreAudio lately, I recommend you to take a look at Novocaine, it might just be all you need: http://alexbw.github.com/novocaine/ You most likely already found out that CoreAudio is rather complex.

Answer (score 3):

I've written two Blog-Entries about this issue and how to get equalization on iOS working. It uses the libsox library (cross compiled).

First post explains how you build libsox: http://uberblo.gs/2011/04/iosiphoneos-equalizer-with-libsox-making-it-a-framework

The second explains how to use it: http://uberblo.gs/2011/04/iosiphoneos-equalizer-with-libsox-doing-effects

please up the answer if it helped you! thanks!

Comment: You're first link got cut off. The correct link is http://uberblo.gs/2011/04/iosiphoneos-equalizer-with-libsox-making-it-a-framework The script works great btw. Thanks for posting that.

Comment: You might be interested in my library I wrote for iOS to do all sorts of filters in just a few lines of code: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP

Answer (score 2):

you can implement using same classes as used in speak here sample code ,only to generate properties like peak powervalue and average powervalue you need to do calculation in callback function and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This ancient [Motorola AN2110 App Note](http://www.chameleon.synth.net/files/developer/pdf/motorola/AN2110.pdf) explains how to write your own fully controllable 10-band equalizer (and 10 bands of real-time audio IIR filters will consume well under 10% of an iPod Touch's ARM CPU).  Not sure about how to integrate this with an AU Graph, but this type of EQ can easily be integrated into PCM Audio Queue buffer callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! Looks complicated but it sounds like the right direction to follow. André.

Comment: That document doesn't really explain how to integrate that into an iOS environment.