# Modifying Low, Mid, High Frequencies Core Audio IOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

I see that the only effect unit on iOS is the ipod EQ. Is there any other way to change the high, mid and low frequencies of an audio unit on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the iPhone doesn't really allow custom AudioUnits (ie. an AudioUnit's ID cannot be registered for use by an AUGraph). What you can do is register a render callback and process the raw PCM data yourself. Sites like musicdsp.org have sample DSP code that you can utilize to implement any effect you can imagine.

Also, here is a similar StackOverflow question for reference: [How to make a simple EQ AudioUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029079/how-to-make-a-simple-eq-audiounit-bass-mid-treble-with-ios)

Comment: Great thanks. I will have a look. Some of it looks like a challenge, which is always good. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of built-in Audio Units including a set of filters, delay and even reverb. A good clue is to look in AUComponent.h. You will need to get their ABSD's properly setup otherwise they throw an error or produce silence. But they do work.

Comment: They do work on iOS. As i say, check the headers, they reveal all. Apple doc's has never been helpful or up to date so i find reading through the header files can really reveal a lot!

Comment: Great thanks I will have a look. This audio programming is tricky, but fun. :/