# iPhone audio equalizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am playing video from the web with `AVPlayerLayer` :

```
AVAsset *newAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:newAsset];

audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:newPlayerItem];

avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:audioPlayer];
```

And i want to be able to add `Audio Equalizer` to the video. Something like :

```
Pop, Flat, Balled, Blues, Classical, Dance, Metal
```

I search for and documentation for this in Google and in apple developer program resources and didn't find nothing.
And i also noticed that some apps have this function, but it's for iOS 6.1 only.

Any help with this issue? Did apple have something build-in or it's a non-apple source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Stack Overflow question has answers offering several different solutions: [How to make a simple EQ AudioUnit (bass, mid, treble) with iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029079/how-to-make-a-simple-eq-audiounit-bass-mid-treble-with-ios)