# Build advance equaliser in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, avplayer, audiounit

I build a music player app using AVplayer. The app access and play songs from iPod library. This is how I play mediaItem using `AVPlayer`

```
MPMediaItem *mediaItem = ...
NSURL *assetUrl = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:assetUrl];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

I need to add graphical equaliser to my app to allow users to change the following values

[image] [image]

It seems audio processing in iOS is different from other frameworks. I did an R&D and found

- Audio unit
- MTAudioProcessingTap
- NVDSP
- Novocaine
- OpenAL

My questions are,
Is it possible to create custom equaliser with AVPlayer?
What technology should I use for my requirement (creating a custom equaliser with AVPlayer)?

P.S. Can any one give a simple working example which I can add to the project and check the changes in the song (I tried the apple documentations, but it is not clear)

**Update**

btw I built my own eq & processing lib 
https://github.com/clementprem/CPAudioPlayer

Comment: Hey maybe this link could help,

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029079/how-to-make-a-simple-eq-audiounit-bass-mid-treble-with-ios>

Comment: @Clement Prem: Could you please provide an example on your Github repo? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`AVPlayer` will be of no use to you, since it only provides a high level interface.

I implemented an audio equaliser some time ago and my suggestion is going with Novocaine, which uses NVDSP and Audio Unit (and makes it simpler, actually). Novocaine even includes an `Equalizer` class, so you just need integrating it into your app (if you do not do streaming, that is really straightforward).

Comment: I need to support background & remote control event handling & other basic functionalities of a music app. Is it possible with Novocaine?

Comment: background, remote control etc. are all fine with audio units. novocaine really gives you an almost ready-made solution for you. AVPlayer provides a very simple interface, audio unit is what you need.

Comment: I agree. I've made this in [KREAFUNK](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kreafunk-listen-to-anything/id807353001?mt=8). You need to build your own audio graph or use a 3rd party library like [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) or [The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com).

Comment: @Trenskow I checked you app it is cool.  what did you use for the equaliser & for music player? (hope u don't have any NDA related issue :) )

Comment: I build an audio graph using the AUGraph and AudioUnit APIs. It's not for the faint of hearted. C API and very strict thread synchronization issues. I think I would have used something like Novocaine today if I should start over. :)

Comment: @Trenskow ok. Btw I created a music player using Augraph & audio unit. Btw I had a look at Navocaine but how can we add audio unit to novocaine player. For example iPod eq (kAudioUnitProperty_PresentPreset)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by NOVOCAINE.

Take the code to instantiate a NVPeakingEQFilter:

```
    NVPeakingEQFilter* PEQ = [[NVPeakingEQFilter alloc] initWithSamplingRate:self.samplingRate];
    PEQ.Q = QFactor;
    PEQ.G = gain;
    PEQ.centerFrequency = centerFrequencies;
```

you need define 3 parameters: Q, G, and centerFrequency. Both Q and centerFrequency are usually fixed (QFactor in my case is a constant equal to 2.0).

So, you have 10 sliders: each one corresponds to a fixed centerFrequency. I suggested iTunes values: 32Hz, 64Hz, 125Hz, 250Hz, 500Hz, 1KHz, 2KHz, 4KHz, 8KHz, 16KHz. You do not want to change those values when the slider value changes.

What you want to change when the slider value changes is the gain (G). At init time, G can be set to 0.0. This means "no amplification/attenuation".

When the slider moves, you change G, so actually you would do:

PEQ[sender.tag - 1].G = sender.value * kNominalGainRange;

where kNominalGainRange is 12.0, so if sender.value goes from -1.0 to +1.0, G goes from -12 to +12.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote an AUGraph library from scratch :)

Comment: than i am too late to write this answer:)

Comment: I haven't tried it, just read some code, then I realized that NVPeakingEQFilter is a class of NVDSP library. So maybe you need to add both library:
- https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine
- https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP